# Imagemagick: fill white color dimension taken from GIMP

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

Say there is a following image. I'd like to fill the part with letters `ry` with white color (`ry` is an example for a question). It can be done by the following command:

```
mogrify -fill white -draw "rectangle <coordinates, size>" *.jpg
```

I'd like to know how do I "convert" selection of `ry` part of the image from GIMP to be understood by `imagemagick`? In other words, given selection made in GIMP, what values do I use instead of `<coordinates, size>`?

[image]

As per request, I show how GIMP coordinates look:

[image]

On a side node, I use the following command to crop image using `mogrify` when using coordinates from GIMP `mogrify -crop 0x0+4248+6336 *.jpg`

where 0 -> position from left, 0 -> position from right
4248 -> size from left, 6336 -> size from right
Perhaps this helps.

Comment: What is your selection from GIMP?  Your question is not clear.  Do you want to fill some rectangular shape or just change the letters "ry" to pure white or something else?

Comment: Only Gimp knows the coordinates (which are not really coordinates, but a mask). And if the selection is exactly on the letters, filling only the selection is going to leave a faint gap. If you obtain the selection in Gimp, why don't you make the fill in Gimp, too?

Comment: @fmw42 I want to fill a rectangular shape.

Comment: @xenoid I have a lot of images so I'd like to change them in batch.

Comment: How do you obtain the selection? If you have to do that manually, then the fill is trivial do add (with a short gimp script in the worst case)? When processing a lot of images, the time-consuming part is the file load/save dialog, there is a script to "save+close current image, open next in sequence" that makes this instance if assigned to a keystroke.

Comment: Give us an example of the GIMP coordinates or the mask used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume your coordinates are top-left corner, width and height, then there are two ways to fill white in Imagemagick.  The first is to overlay a white image. The second is to draw a white rectangle.

Overlay White Image:

```
convert ry.jpg -size 389x260 xc:white -geometry +1179+486 -compose over -composite result.jpg

-size specifies the size of the white image
-geometry specifies the top left corner of the white image in the background image
```

[image]

Draw White Rectangle:

```
convert ry.jpg -fill white -draw "rectangle 1179,486 1568,746" -alpha off result2.jpg

The top-left corner and the bottom-right corner coordinates are used
```

[image]

Comment: It's working flawlessly! Thank you very much!

Comment: One question thought. How do I convert `convert` command to `mogrify`?  When I run this in batch I get  the following error among others:`mogrify: no encode delegate for this image format XC @ warning/constitute.c/WriteImage/1399.`

Comment: Use the -draw command instead!  The composite command is harder to do in mogrify. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose